# 'ON a spaceship' v. 'IN a spaceship'

Tags: prepositions

On the one hand, you can use both the preposition 'on' and 'in' with the noun 'plane'. On the other hand, you only use 'on' with 'ship'. On yet another hand, you use 'in' with 'car'. What preposition should I use with 'spaceship'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine. The "on" in "on a bus" refers to being on a route.

"On a spaceship" sounds like it is a type of space bus, something that is quite commonplace, and following a standard well known route.

> I'm on the 15:30 Red Rocket from Huston to the moon, could you meet me at the spaceport at 17:00 Lunar time?

"In a spaceship" if it isn't following a standard path.

> We're in a spaceship, exploring the Beta Octant.

Just like a bus follows a fixed route (on a bus) but a car could go anywhere (in a car)

The "on" in "on a bike" is not "on a route" but "sitting on".